# NuxtJs not passing prop to subcomponent

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

This is my page named "index.vue" in pages directory, folder "blogs".

```
<template>
  <blog-grid :v-if="blogsList.length>0" :v-for="item in blogsList" :item="item"></blog-grid>
</template>

<script>
export default {
      async asyncData(context) {
        let $axios=context['$axios']
        let res = await $axios.$get('http://localhost:3001/blogs')
        return {
          blogsList: res.blog_items,
        }
      },
    created() {
          console.log(this.blogsList)
    }
  }
</script>
```

I get blogsList in console, all's fine. Now I expect that component gets its prop 'item', but hell no.
This is blog-grid.vue in components folder

```
<template>
  <div :id="item.id"></div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['item'],
    data(){
      console.log(this.item)
    },
    mounted(){
      console.log(this.item)
    }
  }
</script>
```

And I get two undefined here and nuxt error that "item" is not properly registered.

This is a normal Vue components behaviour and would work in browser, but not in Nuxtjs. I passed the prop, what's wrong with it?

What bugs me more is that the same structure works in another page folder "products", just don't get it.

What am I doing wrong here? Why prop is not passed?

UPD: If I change variable "item" to say "index" in index.vue it fails with error "index" is not defined but referenced during render. Wwhhaatt???

UPD: If I change asyncData return to this:

```
return {
          blogsList: res.blog_items[0],
        }
```

and get rid of loop, just passing the item then It goes well, no errors. So the trouble is with array loop. Typeof shows Object, Array is fine I see no problems here. Totally stumbled.

UPD: I made the stupidiest mistake possible. I found it and it was here

```
<blog-grid :v-if="blogsList.length>0" :v-for="item in blogsList" :item="item"></blog-grid>
```

v-if and v-for are v-bounded and should not be. My god, what a cringe.

Comment: Debug `blogsList`, it is very likely not what you expect. Also remove `console` from `data`. That line there doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It's probably because your component `blog-grid.vue` is mounted while you're still fetching data from the backend, that's why it's undefined. Also, do not use `v-for` + `v-if`: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for You could probably also use the new `fetch` hook from Nuxt: it does have handy helpers like `$fetchState.pending`: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the stupidiest mistake possible. I found it and it was here

```
<blog-grid :v-if="blogsList.length>0" :v-for="item in blogsList" :item="item"></blog-grid>
```

v-if and v-for are v-bounded and should not be. My god, what a cringe.

updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2: okay, so here is the [github repo](https://github.com/kissu/so-test-fetch-ssr) of the whole project. It is hosted (static so) on Netlify here: https://use-nuxt-fetch-hook-on-api.netlify.app/
It's totally SEO friendly since it's Nuxt doing it's SSR job upfront. Even tho, it is using `fetch() hook`, you can totally find, let's say "Clementina DuBuque" in the source code (`ctrl + u`) since it's generated at the buld time. You can also double-check this by disabling your Javascript on this specific page.

So, to sum up on your latest comment:

> 1. Because you are wrong about inferiority of asyncData since it is much better SEO oriented

The SEO is exactly the same here. No benefit on one or the other on the SSR part, while it's built.

> 2. It works and is not inferior and should not be claimed as inferior just because you think so or not comfortable with it.

I can repeat myself by pasting my own comment up here if you wish. Here, everything is explained properly:
"`asyncdata` is just inferior to fetch because it blocks the page and the user needs to wait in the middle of the process without any visual feedback nor a super great experience. you could use a `skeleton` (buefy.org/documentation/skeleton) and `fetch`, that way it will load the page, continue loading the data and display it like facebook, youtube and alike. you also do not have access to the handy helpers and you rely on your own logic: more code, more bugs possible. you also cannot use this in `asyncData` nor benefit from caching (`timestamp` helper)"

I recommended this since it does have those benefits, on top of how you do handle the data overall. I am comfortable with both of them. Just saying that **in my opinion**, `fetch` is better. Still, I provided an example with both implementations if you do not like mine. :D

> 3. Well my mistake was not it asyncData vs Fetch.

Your issue was with `v-for` and `v-if` too indeed. That's why I wrote you an example without this mistake. Sorry if I should have emphased it more.

That said, I don't know why you're so aggressive with the free help I do provide you. I do only try to help you. If you don't want to upvote, accept or whatever, you do you. No hard feelings here. Just sad that you do have that kind of attitude when somebody gives it's time to solve on of your issues.

That said, not even trying some of my solutions nor providing code relevant to the issue is not constructive. So yeah, I may avoid spending more time if you have those reactions, unfortunately.

---

EDIT: not the recommended way IMO but still, here is the `asyncData` variant for the same code: https://codesandbox.io/s/use-nuxt-async-data-hook-on-api-nisfj?file=/pages/index.vue

---

I've written an example for you here: https://codesandbox.io/s/use-nuxt-fetch-hook-on-api-5ymdz?file=/pages/index.vue

It shows you how to:

- use the `fetch` hook, not confuse with the `fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")` one !
- how to use the `$fetchState.pending` helper
- I've added a `delay` function just that you can see a bit better how it works
- properly set the props on the children

`index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="p-4">
    <div v-if="$fetchState.pending" class="loading">Loading...</div>
    <span v-else-if="$fetchState.error">Error...</span>
    <display-item
      v-else
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item.id"
      :item="item"
    ></display-item>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

export default {
  async fetch() {
    await delay(3000);
    const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log("json", json);
    this.items = json;
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

`DisplayItem.vue` (the child)

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: sorry for taking so long. I see that you've changed asyncdata to fetch hook. But why? What's wrong with asyncdata? Docs say that both methods depend on architecture and I do not understand why asyncdata does not work. Therefore I can not yet accept your answer since I do not understand what's wrong with my example.

Comment: `asyncdata` is just inferior to `fetch` because it blocks the page and the user needs to wait in the middle of the process without any visual feedback nor a super great experience. you could use a skeleton (https://buefy.org/documentation/skeleton/) and `fetch`, that way it will load the page, continue loading the data and display it like facebook, youtube and alike. you also do not have access to the handy helpers and you rely on your own logic: more code, more bugs possible. you also cannot use `this` in `asyncData` nor benefit from caching (`timestamp` helper). Want an `asyncData` example ?

Comment: That's the point. I need a full SSR and I need the page to be ready before it starts to load in the browser. Otherwise I would not use NuxtJS at all and just lazy load everything on the client. I would love to see asyncData example, thanks.

Comment: `fetch` is working on the SSR too. Actually, you could make your content on build time but it's probably not the case here. And even if you do, it will be hydrated + lazy-loaded in the same way if you're using `asyncData` or `fetch`. The differences I gave are pretty much the only ones. More details in the docs: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching/#the-fetch-hook

Comment: I understand all that, but I need my content to be server ready. So I yet want to understand what's wrong with my example before I stick to another method. Both methods are supported and recommended and none is inferior, so if you please explain what is wrong in my case. Because in another file just like this it all works and I do not want to switch before I understand it. Otherwise you say like "I don't know what is wrong, just do it my way", it is not the case here.

Comment: Hm, codesandbox do have issues importing some packages sometimes, fixed !

Comment: Your example works in browser but not server-side. Same error as before, prop is not passed. To be precise: object is passed, but not array.

Comment: I found my mistake, updated my answer. I can not nor vote up your answer nor vote up your comments: 1. Because you are wrong about inferiority of asyncData since it is much better SEO oriented 2. It works and is not inferior and should not be claimed as inferior just because you think so or not comfortable with it. 3. Well my mistake was not it asyncData vs Fetch. 

Sorry mate.